# perl subroutine reference can't get value

Tags: perl

This code is to read the blast file,  in this subroutines

```
parse_blast($filename, \$beginning, \$ending, \@HSPs);
```

it seems can't get @HSPs value by reference, I can't find why it can't get value. all subroutines seems works i can also directly print value in sub parse_one_HSP.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $filename = q/..\test\input.txt/;
my ($beginning, $ending);
my @HSPs;

parse_blast($filename, \$beginning, \$ending, \@HSPs); #Can't get the HSPs value
print $beginning;

foreach my $t(@HSPs){
    print_HSP(%{$t});  #can't print anything here
}
print $ending; 


sub print_HSP{
    my(%HSP)=@_;
    print "\n-> Expect value:   $HSP{expect}\n";
    print "\n-> Query string:   $HSP{query}\n";
    print "\n-> Query range:    $HSP{query_range}\n";
    print "\n-> Subject String: $HSP{subject}\n";
    print "\n-> Subject range:  $HSP{subject_range}\n";
}

sub parse_blast {
    my ($filename, $beginning_ref, $ending_ref, $HSPs) = @_;
    # parse the blast output into 3 sections
    my ($part1, $part2, $part3); # beginning, alignments and ending
    my $in_beginning = 0;
    my $in_alignment = 0;
    my $in_ending = 0;
    open IN, $filename || die;
    while (<IN>) {
        if (/^T?BLAST[NPX]/) {$in_beginning = 1}
        if (/^ALIGNMENTS/) {$in_beginning = 0; $in_alignment = 1; next}
        if (/^\s\sDatabase/) {$in_alignment = 0; $in_ending = 1;}
        if ($in_beginning) {$part1 .= $_;}
        if ($in_alignment) {$part2 .= $_;}
        if ($in_ending) {$part3 .= $_;}
    }
    close IN;

    $$beginning_ref = $part1;
    $$ending_ref = $part3;
    # split the alignments into an array
    my @alignments;
    split_alignments($part2, \@alignments);
    # parse each alignment
    foreach my $alignment (@alignments) {
        parse_one_alignment($alignment, \@$HSPs);
    }
}

sub split_alignments{
    my ($alignments, $aligns) = @_;
    my @alignment;
    while ($alignments =~ /^>.*\n(^(?!>).*\n)+/gm) {
        push @$aligns, $&;
    }
}

sub parse_one_alignment{
    my ($align, $HSPs) = @_;
    my ($part1, $part2) = $align =~ /(.*?)( Score =.*)/s;

    while ($part2 =~ /^ Score =.*\n(^(?! Score =).*\n)+/mg) {
        my %hsp;
        parse_one_HSP($part2, \%hsp);

        push @$HSPs, %hsp;
    }
}

sub parse_one_HSP {
    my ($data, $hsp) = @_;
    #my $hsp = shift; # reference to hash

    # parsing one HSP ...

    # declare and initialize variables
    my($expect) = '';
    my($query) = '';
    my($query_range) = '';
    my($subject) = '';
    my($subject_range) = '';

    ($expect) = ($data =~ /Expect = (\S+)/);

    $query = join ( '' , ($data =~ /^Query.*\n/gm) );

    $subject = join ( '' , ($data =~ /^Sbjct.*\n/gm) );

    $query_range = join('..', ($data =~ /(\d+).*\D(\d+)/s));

    $subject_range = join('..', ($data =~ /(\d+).*\D(\d+)/s));

    $query =~ s/[^acgt]//g;

    $subject =~ s/[^acgt]//g;

    $hsp->{expect} = $expect;
    $hsp->{query} = $query;
    $hsp->{query_range} = $query_range;
    $hsp->{subject} = $subject;
    $hsp->{subject_range} = $subject_range;
    #print_HSP(%$hsp);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'cant get the `@HSPs` value'? `@HSPs` is empty when you call parse_blast().

BTW It would be much easier to help if you indented the code in the blocks.

Comment: Also, your `\@$HSPs` is decidedly wrong. Just use `$HSPs`.

Comment: `open IN, $filename || die;` is incorrect because `||` is binding stronger than `,`.  It needs to be written `open(IN, $filename) || die;`    though I'd really recommend: 
`open(my $in, '<', $filename) or die;`

See http://perlmaven.com/always-use-3-argument-open

Comment: If I were you, I'd probably did not try to pass around references. I's just use global variables. Once that works and if it is really necessary then I might think of building a class.
You could just use the global variables `$beginning, $ending, @HSPs` that will make the code much simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using too many references to scalars and hashes can lead to confusion about which variable is what. Also, you should avoid passing return variables in function parameters. The cool thing about Perl is that you can return multiple variables from a function, unlike C.

Here is a cleanup of your code. I was not able to test it, since I do not have any input data, but it should be doing what you expect:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $filename = q/..\test\input.txt/;
my ($beginning, $ending, @HSPs) = parse_blast($filename); 

print $beginning;    
foreach my $t (@HSPs){
   print_HSP($t);  #can't print anything here
}
print $ending; 

sub print_HSP{
    my($HSP) = @_;
    print "\n-> Expect value:   $HSP->{expect}\n";
    print "\n-> Query string:   $HSP->{query}\n";
    print "\n-> Query range:    $HSP->{query_range}\n";
    print "\n-> Subject String: $HSP->{subject}\n";
    print "\n-> Subject range:  $HSP->{subject_range}\n";
}

sub parse_blast {
    my ($filename) = @_;
    # parse the blast output into 3 sections
    my ($beginning, $alignments, $ending) = ("","","");
    my $in_beginning = 0;
    my $in_alignment = 0;
    my $in_ending = 0;
    open(my $IN, "<", $filename) || die;
    while (<$IN>) {
        if (/^T?BLAST[NPX]/) {
            $in_beginning = 1;
        }
        if (/^ALIGNMENTS/) {
            $in_beginning = 0;
            $in_alignment = 1;
            next;
        }
        if (/^\s\sDatabase/) {
            $in_alignment = 0;
            $in_ending = 1;
        }

        $beginning  .= $_ if $in_beginning;
        $alignments .= $_ if $in_alignment;
        $ending     .= $_ if $in_ending;
    }
    close $IN;

    # split the alignments into an array
    # and parse each alignment
    my @HSPs;
    foreach my $alignment (split_alignments($alignments)) {
        push @HSPs, parse_one_alignment($alignment);
    }
    return ($beginning, $ending, @HSPs);
}

sub split_alignments{
    my ($alignments) = @_;
    my @aligns = ($alignments =~ /^>.*\n (?: ^(?!>).*\n )+/gmx);
    return @aligns;
}

sub parse_one_alignment{
    my ($align) = @_;
    my ($part2) = $align =~ /( Score =.*)/s;

    my @HSPs;
    while ($part2 =~ /^\s Score \s =.*\n (?:^(?!\s Score \s =).*\n)+/mgx) {
        push @HSPs, parse_one_HSP($part2);
    }
    return @HSPs;
}

sub parse_one_HSP {
    my ($data) = @_;

    my ($expect) = ($data =~ /Expect = (\S+)/);

    my $query = join '' , ($data =~ /^Query.*\n/gm);
    $query =~ tr/acgt//cd;

    # FIXME "Sbjct" contains a "c"
    my $subject = join '' , ($data =~ /^Sbjct.*\n/gm);
    $subject =~ tr/acgt//cd;

    my $query_range = join '..', ($data =~ /(\d+).*\D(\d+)/s);

    my $subject_range = join '..', ($data =~ /(\d+).*\D(\d+)/s);

    return {
        expect        => $expect,
        query         => $query,
        query_range   => $query_range,
        subject       => $subject,
        subject_range => $subject_range,
    };
}
```